# sendSynchronousRequest:urlrequest returningResponse:&responce error:&error is unavilable in WatchOS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, watchkit

I want to get data from API on WatchOS for that I use `NSURLConnection` but I get error is not available in WatchOS2, Here I add my code which I use please see & help me, thanks

```
NSURLRequest *urlrequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0"]];
NSURLResponse *responce = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlrequest returningResponse:&responce error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSString *currentWeather = nil;
NSArray* weather = allData[@"weather"];
for (NSDictionary *theWeather in weather)
 {
  currentWeather = theWeather[@"main"];
 }
 self.lbl.text = currentWeather;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` is being deprecated from iOS9 onwards. So you should be looking into `NSURLSession` APIs. As for this particular error, this API(`sendSynchronousRequest :`) is WatchOS prohibited. `command+click` on this API and you will see `__WATCHOS_PROHIBITED` flag.

NSURLSession provides `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` as alternate. However this is not a synchronous call. So you need to change your code a bit and do the work after `completionHandler` is reached. Use below code

```
NSURLRequest *urlrequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0"]];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlrequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          NSMutableDictionary *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
          //Here you do rest of the stuff.
}] resume];
```

Comment: its work now thanks a lot for help , i use NSURLSession

Comment: It's great that you solved it yourself. I just added the code.